# Text in Border of input textbox

Tags: html, css, angular, border

[Please click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQ8OL.png)I would like to see something like text name on the border for input box.

The HTML is -

```
<input type="text"
       id="text creator"
       class="form-control" placeholder="text creator"
       name="object-creator"/>
```

`"text creator"` should appear on the border.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by on the border?

Comment: you cannot with placeholder, you have to use label with input

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your answer, I need the text on the outline of input text box itself. Not as a separate lable or other border

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "on the border", so here are two options that I think you might be after.

Using a fieldset / legend, the legend is placed "on the border" of the fieldset.

```
<fieldset>
<legend>text creator</legend>

<input type="text"
   id="text creator"
   class="form-control"
   name="object-creator"/> 
</fieldset>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jafarian/n5ocxpod/

Alternatively, if you just mean above the input field, use a label:

```
<label for="text creator">text creator</label><br>
<input type="text"
   id="text creator"
   class="form-control"
   name="object-creator"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jafarian/hjv74tdw/106/

Edit based on comments: This one still uses labels (rather than a placeholder), but aligns the label to overlap the border of the input field, and sets its z-index to appear on top of the input field. Make sure your background colours match your label background!:
https://jsfiddle.net/jafarian/04493rbu/

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your answer, I need the text on the outline of input text box itself. Not as a separate lable or other border @J.Afarian

Comment: So you don't want to use labels? Do you have an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Yes, I have an image, but I am not able to upload in comments in stackoverfolw :( .

Comment: Hi have added a image link in the starting of the original post

Comment: I added a new fiddle to the bottom of my answer, is that any closer to what you're after? It uses labels (not placeholder text like in your original post).